# Create a copy of custom view and add as new subview

Tags: ios, view, swift3, copy

I just created a custom view class and it has many properties. And user can have option to change its properties like color , background color. 
I want to give option to copy and paste in my app.

Solution 1: - 
Create a method of copy. Create new object of view then manually assign all properties to new object and return a that object.

Any other solution???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A view is a presenter for a model. For example in your project model should has properties colour, background colour, and so on.
To support a copy feature, you should copy a model instance and initiate a new object of the view to present the new model.
It is a more clear solution for that problem.
Also it will allow you to create store to models (a layer that will contain some logic to manage models, this layer will not know about UI).